# How to check convergence of sequence in complete metric space.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two sequences in a complete metric space $(X,d)$ such that
>
> 1. $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\le\frac{1}{n^2}$
> 2. $d(y_n,y_{n+1})\le \frac{1}{n}$ , for all $n\in \mathbb{N}.$
>
> Then which sequence would converge? Justify.

Now since the space is complete so every Cauchy sequence is convergent. Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$, the usual metric.  So I take the sequence of partial sums of Harmonic series $\{H_n\}_{n\ge1}$, then

$$d(H_n,H_{n+1})=|H_{n+1}-H_n|=1/(n+1)\le1/n$$ 
But $H_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence so it does not converge in $X$.

So 2 need not converge.

Is my reasoning correct? Also I have a feeling that 1 would always converge, but I haven't be able to prove it. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: for large $M < N,$ how big is $\sum_{j =M+1}^N \; \frac{1}{j^2} \; \; ? $

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is good.

For 2, use the triangle inequality to show that, for $m < n$,
$$d(x_n, x_m) \le \sum_{k = m}^{n - 1} d(x_k, x_{k+1}).$$
Cauchiness follows from the convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.